# Calculate factorial in C# using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

I know how to calculate a factorial using a loop. Below is the code for loop, but I am getting an error while doing it by recursion. Below are both the code samples. How can I fix this?

```
namespace factorial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i, number, fact;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            fact = number;
            for (i = number - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nFactorial of Given Number is: "+fact);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Factorial using recursion:

Is there something as where I am going wrong? When am I calculating it using recursion?

Factorial using loop:

```
public double factorial_Recursion(int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return number * factorial_recursion(number - 1);
}

public double factorial_WhileLoop(int number)
{
    double result = 1;
    while (number != 1)
    {
        result = result * number;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: An error .. please explain

Comment: Where is your recursive function?

Comment: @ Karel I have edited my question and have added my recursive function. Which I think have some error.

Comment: When asking for help about an error, it is quite helpful to include details on the error.  What kind of error?  What line?  What is the error message?  Remember, we can't see your screen.

Comment: @Amy I am getting (11:11) Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.

Comment: Okay, you're getting a compiler error.  On what line?

Comment: You have a typo in the code.  Inside the method you are calling `factorial_recursion` (lower case r in recursion) whereas the name of the method is `factorial_Recursion` (upper case R).  With regards to your error, I'm guessing you have placed the code outside a class or something like that.  Methods must be inside a class.  I tested the method in Linqpad and it seemed to work ok.

Comment: C# is case-sensitive so you need to call the function like factorial_Recursive(number-1). Note the Upper case letter?

Comment: In your while loop version, what causes the loop to exit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call name is not equal to your method name:

```
factorial_Recursion is the method name.
factorial_recursion is the call.
```

This worked for me:

```
namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(factorial_Recursion(5));
            Console.WriteLine("press any Key");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static double factorial_Recursion(int number)
        {
            if (number == 1)
                return 1;
            else
                return number*factorial_Recursion(number - 1);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly.

Comment: Please add a if case to check if number is equal to zero:

static int Factorial(int number)
        {
            if (number == 0 || number == 1)
                return 1;

            return number * Factorial(number - 1);
        }